# WebDriver-Manager not updating chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I am struggling with chromedriver for Selenium. Ever since the new version of Chrome was released it stopped working even though I was using WebDriver Manager by Boni Garcia which is meant to update it automatically.

Currently whenever I run it, Chrome comes up blank with `data:,` in the address bar.

I've seen some thread saying the WebDriver Manager is not working as expected anymore but it was quite old and the setup was working fine for me for a while.

One thing I noticed is that a Maven library in my InteliJ seems to not match the latest release on Boni's github.

Comparing what I have in versions.properties:

[image: version properties from my InteliJ]

Against Boni's github:

[image: version properties from Boni's github]

My pom file (based on Boni's learning projects) :

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>SeleniumWithJava</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <slf4j.version>2.0.6</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.4.5</logback.version>

    <selenium.version>4.8.1</selenium.version>
    <junit5.version>5.9.2</junit5.version>
    <assertj.version>3.24.2</assertj.version>
    <wdm.version>5.3.2</wdm.version>

    <htmlunit.version>4.8.0</htmlunit.version>
    <rerunner.version>2.1.6</rerunner.version>
    <junit-platform.version>1.9.2</junit-platform.version>
    <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
    <browsermob.version>2.1.5</browsermob.version>
    <zapclient.version>1.11.0</zapclient.version>
    <axel.version>4.6.0</axel.version>
    <selenide.version>6.12.0</selenide.version>
    <datafaker.version>1.8.0</datafaker.version>
    <extentreports.version>5.0.9</extentreports.version>
    <allure.version>2.21.0</allure.version>
    <allure-maven.version>2.12.0</allure-maven.version>
    <cucumber.version>7.11.1</cucumber.version>
    <spring-boot.version>3.0.3</spring-boot.version>
    <appium.version>8.3.0</appium.version>
    <rest-assured.version>5.3.0</rest-assured.version>

    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M9</maven-surefire-plugin.version>

    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

    <project.encondig>UTF-8</project.encondig>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encondig}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encondig}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${htmlunit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit5.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>${wdm.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-grid</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.artsok</groupId>
        <artifactId>rerunner-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${rerunner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
        <version>${browsermob.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zaproxy</groupId>
        <artifactId>zap-clientapi</artifactId>
        <version>${zapclient.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.deque.html.axe-core</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
        <version>${axel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>${selenide.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
                <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.datafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>datafaker</artifactId>
        <version>${datafaker.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>${extentreports.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${appium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <!-- The following setup is only required when using Allure -->
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit5.AllureJunit5</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <!-- /Allure -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-maven.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the testing template I've been using:

```
public class LocatorByLink {

WebDriver driver;

@BeforeEach
void setup(){
    driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
}

@AfterEach
void teardown(){
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
void test(){

}
```

}

Console output:

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome

at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.instantiateDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1775)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.create(WebDriverManager.java:425)
at com.handsonselenium.chapter003.examples.LocatorByLink.setup(LocatorByLink.java:19)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:78)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$23(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:505)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:174)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.quit()" because "this.driver" is null
    at com.handsonselenium.chapter003.examples.LocatorByLink.teardown(LocatorByLink.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptAfterEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeAfterEachMethodAdapter$24(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:510)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachMethods$10(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:243)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$14(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:276)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:275)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:241)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:142)
    ... 48 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createLocalWebDriver(WebDriverCreator.java:64)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.createLocalWebDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1949)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.instantiateDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1764)
... 76 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:49892/devtools/browser/3d746805-ea32-49e3-9d0e-6810f1d7b998
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.5', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107)
at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.(Connection.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:50)
... 84 more

Answer (score 1):

```
You are getting the issue because recently chrome browser updated recently 110 to 111, so the Selenium API call was forbidden for as of now, implement the below solution.

ChromeOptions opt=new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        //Launching the browser
        driver=new ChromeDriver(opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11750

Appears to related with Chrome 111 update.

I added this argument on my webdriver "--remote-allow-origins=*" and it's working for now.

```
public static ChromeDriver getChromeDriver() {
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}
```