# How to update Maven external library?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Using InteliJ with Maven on MacOS BigSur.
I have an external Maven library for the WebDriver Manager. The dependency that I have for that is following:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I look into the library under External Libraries and compare it against the content of the library on Github I can see that the library on my computer is not up to date - missing some recent changes from couple of days ago.

At the same time, the version of the WebDriver Manager didn't change, it was just updated to cover new version of the Chrome driver but remains listed as 5.3.2

I feel like this is causing the WebDriver Manager to not update my Chromedriver and selenium tests to fail.

I also had an issue with Maven repos not updating but I got it fixed by clearing the cache folder:

[Maven repos updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCKRe.png)

I thought that the Maven repos not updating was the root cause but it didn't help, the Library in my InteliJ is still out of date and Chromedriver doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly does "compare it against the content of the library on Github" mean?

Comment: Looking through github checking the recent changes I noticed that the versions.properties file was modified -https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/resources/versions.properties 

When I checked the same file within my InteliJ > External Libraries it is missing the most recent content.

Comment: I've attached screenshots of that to my previous question where I was referring to the whole Chrome driver problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715795/webdriver-manager-not-updating-chromedriver

Comment: If you have a look at the pom.xml, the version is 5.3.3-SNAPSHOT, so the next release will be 5.3.3 and include those changes. You can clone the repo and run `mvn install` and then change your version to 5.3.3-SNAPSHOT.